# Fingerprint Scanner FS80 - Raspberry Compatibility

Tags: linux, arm, raspberry-pi, fingerprint

I'm working with a fingerprint scanner futronic FS80 on my Raspberry Pi. It was was verified for pi:
http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Fingerprint_Scanners

I followed the steps to install the scanner with the API library ScanAPI_Ex. 
But, it is not working because the software requires usbfs, and that is not supported by raspbian.

It mention to do this:

```
mount -t usbfs none proc/bus/usb
```

But terminal response:

```
mount: mount point /proc/bus/usb does not exist
```

Comment: Try `mkdir -p /proc/bus/usb`; Ie, just what the error says.  Also, `grep usb /proc/filesystems` should return *usbfs*.  In not, you need `USB_DEVICEFS`  set in Kconfig/Kbuild which is **deprecated**.  Look at [Documentation/usb/proc_usb_info.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/proc_usb_info.txt).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I figured out that raspberry pi has arm architecture. Raspbian OS do not use usbfs /proc/bus/usb, instead it uses /dev/bus/usb.